# Estimate of Hölder Norms (Littlewood–Paley theory)

Tags: real-analysis, inequalities, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, norms

I'm currently studying Littlewood–Paley theory and its application to norm estimate/PDEs by reading Muscalu and Schlag's textbook, where I encountered the following norm estimate problem:

Recall that the Holder norm of a function is defined as follows:
$$[f]_{C^{\alpha}} \mathrel{:=} \lVert f\rVert_{L^{\infty}} + \sup_{x,y}\frac{\lvert f(y)-f(x)\rvert}{\lvert y-x\rvert^{\alpha}}$$
Prove that for any $\alpha \in (0,1)$ and any two functions $f,g \in C^{\alpha}$, we have the following estimate:
$$[fg]_{C^{\alpha}} \leq c(\alpha,d)([f]_{C^{\alpha}}\lVert g\rVert _{L^{\infty}}+[g]_{C^{\alpha}}\lVert f\rVert_{L^{\infty}})$$
where $c=c(\alpha,d) > 0$ is some positive constant depending only on $\alpha$, $d$. I have tried applying the Littlewood–Paley projection operators $P_{k}$ ($k \in \mathbb{Z}$) to $f$ to obtain some estimate of the Hölder norms, but I have made only limited progress. Any hint/idea?

Comment: Do you have a response to the answer below?

Comment: Oh yeah so sorry that I forgot to respond! Thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $a:=\alpha$, $[h]_a:=[h]_{C^a}$, and $\|h\|_\infty:=\|h\|_{L^\infty}$. For any distinct $x$ and $y$,
\begin{align*}
    |f(x)g(x)-f(y)g(y)|&=|f(x)g(x)-f(y)g(x)+f(y)g(x)-f(y)g(y)| \\ 
    &\le|f(x)g(x)-f(y)g(x)|+|f(y)g(x)-f(y)g(y)| \\ 
    &=|f(x)-f(y)|\,|g(x)|+|g(x)-g(y)|\,|f(y)| \\ 
    &\le[f]_a|x-y|^a\,\|g\|_\infty+[g]_a|x-y|^a\,\|f\|_\infty, 
\end{align*}
whence
\begin{align*}
    \frac{|f(x)g(x)-f(y)g(y)|}{|x-y|^a}&\le[f]_a\,\|g\|_\infty+[g]_a\,\|f\|_\infty.  
\end{align*}
Also,
\begin{equation}
\|fg\|_\infty\le\|f\|_\infty\|g\|_\infty\le[f]_a\,\|g\|_\infty\le[f]_a\,\|g\|_\infty+[g]_a\,\|f\|_\infty.   
\end{equation}
So,
\begin{equation}
    [fg]_a\le2([f]_a\,\|g\|_\infty+[g]_a\,\|f\|_\infty),
\end{equation}
as desired.